# How are the "you might like these products" in online marketplaces implemented?

Tags: algorithm, e-commerce

Some e-commerce platforms have the suggestion feature where they tell you once you have an item in the basket that "you might like this product as well". Some, like Amazon, rely on the preexisting data on customer behaviour and their feature is called "Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought" but some seem to suggest by other means.

What are these "other means"? What kind of algorithms do they use in webstores for this capability?

Comment: Google search for Data mining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Majority of suggestions on e-commerce pages are created using some sort of a recommender system (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system). There are tools like Mahout (http://mahout.apache.org/) which already have implementation of most common approaches.

Answer (score 6):

They use data mining, and this particular algorithm you're asking about is called the "nearest neighbor" algorithm.

Here's a link to an article I wrote on the algorithm (as well as many others).

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-weka3/index.html

Answer (score 6):

The process is called `Business Intelligence`, data will be stored in a data warehouse and the business intelligence process can be used using a product such as `SSAS`. The process will involve grouping the volumes of data (Who bought what and when) into `data cubes`.  Analysis is performed on these cubes and used to compare your purchases with others who bought the same product, it will then recommend their purchases (Other customers who bought this, also bought this item....Item X).  Other various AI algorithms are used to compare patterns across other customer trends such as how they shop, where they click etc.  All this data is accumulated and then added to the data cube for analysis.

The data mining algorithms are outlined below, you could look for the `Decision Tree Modelling algorithm` which is how BI determines trends and patterns (In this case, Recommendations):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175595.aspx

Answer (score 2):

the best book about this kind of algorithms is: [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do)

Answer (score 2):

As some of the earlier folks answered, this is called recommendation engine. It is also referred to as Collaborative Filtering technique. There are few tools which does this, Mahout is one of them. Refer to the blog that I have written which talks about a use case where we use [Mahout and Hadoop to build a recommendation engine](https://krishnasblog.com/2012/06/29/implementing-a-recommender-engine-using-hadoop-and-mahout/). As a precursor to this, I have also written a [Component architecture](https://krishnasblog.com/2012/06/24/hadoop-and-mahout-in-data-mining/) of how each of these fit together for a data mining problem.

Mahout will work in standalone mode and also with Hadoop. The decision to use either one really boils down to the size of the historical data that needs to be mined. If the data size is of the order of Terabytes and Petabytes, you typically use Mahout with Hadoop. Weka is another similar open source projects. All these come under a category called machine learning frameworks. I hope it help.